# Gauss Kronrod Rule of numerical integration

Tags: numerical-integration

I tried to make the following numerical integration accurately.

```
\[Xi]1 = 0.999998 - 0.0053014 I;\[Eta]1 = -1.1196366*^8 + 5.403396*^6 I;e0 = 2*10^9;s1 = -0.0009433 + 2.733469*^-7 I;al = 5.6198;
p1 = {{8011.093134 + 329.781879 I}, {1902.0266450 + 
 14.797328 I}, {-1045.822299 + 25.025568 I}, {699.714569 - 
 29.590978 I}, {-515.009091 + 29.013683 I}, {-515.009091 + 
 29.013683 I}, {401.664020 - 27.428940 I}, {-325.798670 + 
 25.727027 I}, {271.880762 - 24.130404 I}, {-231.830775 + 
 22.687591 I}};
w1[x_] := 1/\[Xi]1 + (2*\[Eta]1 - 2)/\[Pi]*1/e0*
NIntegrate[
 Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*p1[[n, 1]]*Cos[u*x]/(1 + s1*Sqrt[u^2 - al^2])*u*
   Sin[u/2]/(u^2 - 4*(n - 1)^2*\[Pi]^2), {n, 1, 10}], {u, 0, 
  al, \[Infinity]}, MaxRecursion -> 100000, 
 Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"];tab1 = Table[{x, Re[#], Im[#]} &[w1[x]], {x, 5/100, 10, 5/100}];
d1 = ListLinePlot[tab1[[1 ;; -1, {1, 2}]], Frame -> True, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 16}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, InterpolationOrder -> 4, PlotRange -> {{0.5, 10}, {-300, 300}}]
```

I tried many Integrate Rules based on similar problems I found here. Only the GaussKronrodRule gives me quick output but with these errors:

NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 400 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 5028.05 +10712.9 I and 22.916945212347706` for the integral and error estimates.

[image]

Is this can be acceptable result? is there any way to improve it?

Comment: So you've tried `Method -> "LevinRule"` and got errors? What version are you using? The `NIntegrate::eincr` error casts doubt on the result; I would seek some confirmation, at least at a few spots scattered over `1/20 <= x <= 10`. It's possible that at most points you get no error.

Comment: Thank you Michael E2. I am using 11.1.0.0 Mathematica version. Yes I have tried LevinRule method and I got this error

Comment: Thank you Michael E2. I am using 11.1.0.0 Mathematica version. Yes I have tried LevinRule method and I got better result specially for x > 8  during longer time compared to "Gauss Kronrod Rule"  with these errors ..(1) NIntegrate::mtdfb: Numerical integration with LevinRule failed. The integration continues with Method -> GaussKronrodRule.  (2) The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 400 ....

Answer (score 4):

Factor out the factors of the sum that do not depend on `n`. For some reason `Factor` (nor `NIntegrate`) can separate them out.  This causes the system for the Levin rule to be large and very slow, sometimes so slow that a time constraint is reached.  With them factored out manually, the integration is moderately fast.  The are a few slow convergence warnings, but no errors indicating the convergence goals were not met.

```
w1[x_] := 
  1/ξ1 + (2*η1 - 2)/π*1/e0*
    NIntegrate[
      Sin[u/2] Cos[u*x] u / (1 + s1*Sqrt[u^2 - al^2]) *
       Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*p1[[n, 1]]/(u^2 - 4*(n - 1)^2*π^2), {n, 1, 10}],
     {u, 0, al, ∞},  (* I don't think the  al  is needed *)
     MaxRecursion -> 20, Method -> "LevinRule"];

tab1 = Monitor[
    Table[{x, Re[#], Im[#]} &[w1[x]], {x, 5/100, 10, 5/100}], 
    x]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {35.227, Null}  *)

d1 = ListLinePlot[tab1[[1 ;; -1, {1, 2}]], Frame -> True, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 16}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, InterpolationOrder -> 4, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.5, 10}, {-300, 300}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Change the `NIntegrate` method to

```
Method -> {"LevinRule", Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 21}}
```

saves 5-6 sec. in computing the `Table`.

The sampling in the plot above is not sufficiently dense, except to give some idea of the magnitude of the oscillation.  For example (takes 50+ sec.):

```
Plot[Re@w1[u], {u, 2, 2.1}, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]